# Grails Rest URL mapping how to use other 'id' then the database 'id'?

Tags: rest, grails, grails-3.0

A question about rest url mappings.. I would like to use a different ​**id**​ in the rest calls then the database id.

Lets say i have an url mapping like this:

```
"/books"(resources:"book")
```

Then the show action would be..

```
def show(Book book) {
    if(book == null) {
        render status:404
    }
    else {
        return [book: book]
    }
}
```

This would load the book belonging the the **id** that was passed in via the rest call like: http://url/books/1

If i want to use a different property of the class Book how would i get the automatic databind working? Assume that my book also has a uuid.
How do i get http://url/books/4860ca28-9a76-480f-b898-fffedda1888f to work in the same way as the database id?

Comment: It's unclear from your question, but the answer is to implement your own RESTful controller which has your own method of looking up your domain classes by a new property other than the id. You could even use the source of the RestulController as an example of how to structure yours. You can't just re-configure Grails to use the built in RestfulController with a different property other than id.

Comment: To supplement @JoshuaMoore's comment, are you looking to search `books` by a property that exists within the `Book` class.